# How can I get the null cateogories to show in this SQL select?

Tags: mysql

Here is the select I have for getting a list of all of the movie categories that actor Kevin Bloom has starred in next to a count of the number of movies of that category starring Kevin.

```
 SELECT category.name, count(*) as kevinCount    
 FROM category    
 JOIN film_category ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id    
 JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id    
 JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id    
 JOIN actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id AND  
 actor.first_name="KEVIN" AND actor.last_name="BLOOM"    
 GROUP BY category.name;
```

I also want this list to include all of the categories that Kevin does not have any movies in. I have tried using different types of join statements to no luck. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `left join` solves the problem of keeping all the categories.  You also need to count the right field:

```
SELECT c.name, count(a.actor_id) as kevinCount    
FROM category c LEFT JOIN
     film_category fc
     ON fc.category_id = c.category_id LEFT JOIN
     film_actor fa
     ON fa.film_id = fc.film_id LEFT JOIN
     actor a
     ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id AND a.first_name = 'KEVIN' AND a.last_name = 'BLOOM'    
GROUP BY c.name;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make a query much easier to write and to read.
- You do not need to join to the table `film`.  The necessary columns are in `film_category` and `film_actor`.
- The same file may be counted more than once, if the film has multiple categories.

Comment: Thank you. I think my real issue was not realizing that I could count a specific column to avoid counting those other things with the left join.

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join`s

```
 SELECT category.name, count(*) as kevinCount    
 FROM category    
 LEFT JOIN film_category ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id    
 LEFT JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id    
 LEFT JOIN film_actor ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id    
 LEFT JOIN actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id 
                AND actor.first_name = 'KEVIN' 
                AND actor.last_name = 'BLOOM'    
 GROUP BY category.name;
```